# Calculate Last Friday of Month in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've written this function to get the last Thursday of the month

```
def last_thurs_date(date):
    month=date.dt.month
    year=date.dt.year
    
    cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
    last_thurs_date = cal[4][4]
    if month < 10:
        thurday_date = str(year)+'-0'+ str(month)+'-' + str(last_thurs_date)
    else:
        thurday_date = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-' + str(last_thurs_date)
    return thurday_date
```

But its not working with the lambda function.

```
datelist['Date'].map(lambda x: last_thurs_date(x))
```

Where datelist is

```
datelist = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = pd.to_datetime('01-01-2014',format='%d-%m-%Y')
                                      , end = pd.to_datetime('06-03-2019',format='%d-%m-%Y'),freq='D').tolist()).rename(columns={0:'Date'})
datelist['Date']=pd.to_datetime(datelist['Date'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jpp already added the solution, but just to add a slightly more readable formatted string - see this [awesome website](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding).

```
import calendar
def last_thurs_date(date):
    year, month = date.year, date.month
    cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
    # the last (4th week -> row) thursday (4th day -> column) of the calendar
    # except when 0, then take the 3rd week (February exception)
    last_thurs_date =  cal[4][4] if cal[4][4] > 0 else cal[3][4] 
    return f'{year}-{month:02d}-{last_thurs_date}'
```

Also added a bit of logic - e.g. you got `2019-02-0` as February doesn't have 4 full weeks.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've just checked and my function isn't actually working. For example April 2014 is wrong. I can't see why though. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Ah thats seems to have fixed it. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Scalar `datetime` objects don't have a `dt` accessor, series do: see [`pd.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html). If you remove this, your function works fine. The key is understanding that [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) passes scalars to your custom function via a loop, not an entire series.

```
def last_thurs_date(date):
    month = date.month
    year = date.year

    cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
    last_thurs_date = cal[4][4]
    if month < 10:
        thurday_date = str(year)+'-0'+ str(month)+'-' + str(last_thurs_date)
    else:
        thurday_date = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-' + str(last_thurs_date)
    return thurday_date
```

You can rewrite your logic more succinctly via f-strings (Python 3.6+) and a ternary statement:

```
def last_thurs_date(date):
    month = date.month
    year = date.year
    last_thurs_date = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)[4][4]
    return f'{year}{"-0" if month < 10 else "-"}{month}-{last_thurs_date}'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, spent hours on this! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I know that a lot of time has passed since the date of this post, but I think it would be worth adding another option if someone came across this thread

Even though I use pandas every day at work, in that case my suggestion would be to just use the datetutil library. The solution is a simple one-liner, without unnecessary combinations.

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY, FR, SA
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# monthly options expiration dates calculated for 2022
monthly_options = list(rrule(MONTHLY, count=12, byweekday=FR, bysetpos=3, dtstart=dt(2022,1,1)))


# last satruday of the month
last_saturday = list(rrule(MONTHLY, count=12, byweekday=SA, bysetpos=-1, dtstart=dt(2022,1,1)))
```

and then of course:

```
pd.DataFrame({'LAST_ST':last_saturdays}) #or whatever you need
```

Answer (score 0):

- This question answer *Calculate Last Friday of Month in Pandas*

  - This can be modified by selecting the appropriate day of the week, here `freq='W-FRI'`
- I think the easiest way is to create a `pandas.DataFrame` using `pandas.date_range` and specifying `freq='W-FRI`.

  - `W-FRI` is Weekly Fridays
  - `pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max(), freq='W-FRI')`

    - Creates all the Fridays in the date range between the min and max of the dates in `df`
  - Use a `.groupby` on `year` and `month`, and select `.last()`, to get the last Friday of every month for every year in the date range.
- Because this method finds all the Fridays for every month in the range and then chooses `.last()` for each month, there's not an issue with trying to figure out which week of the month has the last Friday.
- With this, use [pandas: Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to find values in the `Date` column of the dataframe that are in `last_fridays_in_daterange`.

  - Use the `.isin` method to determine containment.
- [pandas: DateOffset objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data: given a dataframe with a datetime column
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01'), end=pd.to_datetime('2020-08-31'), freq='D')})

# create a dateframe with all Fridays in the daterange for min and max of df.Date
fridays = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max(), freq='W-FRI')})

# use groubpy and last, to get the last Friday of each month into a list
last_fridays_in_daterange = fridays.groupby([fridays.datetime.dt.year, fridays.datetime.dt.month]).last()['datetime'].tolist()

# find the data for the last Friday of the month
df[df.Date.isin(last_fridays_in_daterange)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python function using only Pandas that calculates the last Friday of a given month and year. The function takes a string in the format "YYYY-MM" (e.g., "2024-01") and returns a Pandas Timestamp representing the last Friday of that month.  If required, you can make it timezone aware, e.g. `last_friday_utc = last_friday.tz_localize('UTC') + pd.Timedelta(hours=8)` .

How it Works:

Calculate the Last Day of the Month: The function starts by finding the last day of the specified month using `pd.Timestamp(year_month)` and creates a timestamp for the first day of the given month. Then to get the last day of that month, simply add `pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)`.

Determine the Weekday: Next, it finds out what weekday the last day is. The weekday() method returns an integer representing the day of the week (Monday=0, ..., Sunday=6).

Find the Last Friday: The function then calculates how many days to subtract from the last day to get the previous Friday. This is done by finding the difference in days between the last day's weekday and Friday (represented as 4).

```
def last_friday_of_month(year_month: str):
    """Function to find the last Friday of a given month in a specific year.

    Args:
        year_month: The relevant year and month, e.g. "2024-01".

    Returns:
        The date and time of the last Friday of the specified month and year.
    """
    # Find the last day of the month.
    last_day = pd.Timestamp(year_month) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)

    # Determine the weekday of the last day (Friday is 4).
    weekday = last_day.weekday()

    # Calculate the difference in days to the last Friday.
    days_to_last_friday = (weekday - 4) % 7

    # Subtract the difference to get the last Friday.
    last_friday = last_day - pd.Timedelta(days=days_to_last_friday)

    return last_friday

>>> last_friday_of_month("2024-02")
Timestamp('2024-02-23 00:00:00')
```